# Creating a shortcut on desktop that links to network folder

Tags: networking, batch-file, share, desktop, createfile

I have tried researching this and I can't come up with an answer.  I have a scan folder on the network and would like to have a shortcut created on the desktop.  Variables will be involved.

The folder is "\servername\scans\employee scan folder"  I need the Employee Scan Folder to be the shortcut that is created on the users desktop.

I would like the script to ask me to enter the name of the Employee Scan Folder.

Would I have to use a BAT file or VBS?  In which way can I have a VBS ask me to enter the variable information ("Employee Scan Folder")?

I have little experience with BAT files and no knowledge at all with VBS files.

Thank you all in advance to who have taken the time to help me out!!

Comment: You could do this with `net use` follow by `mklink`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with VBS:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sInput = InputBox("Enter location for Scan Folder","Shortcut")
Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut(objShell.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Employee Scan Folder.LNK")
lnk.TargetPath = chr(34) & sInput & chr(34)
lnk.WorkingDirectory = chr(34) & sInput & chr(34)
'lnk.IconLocation "C:\Programs\Myprogram.exe,1"
lnk.Save
'Clean up 
Set lnk = Nothing
```

Comment: for where it says "Enter Locations for Scan Foler" do I enter \\servername\scan ?  And I'm guessing that when the text box prompts for data, I'll enter the Employee Scan folder, correct?  I'm thinking that it should look like this?

Comment: Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  sInput = InputBox("\\dco-app80\scan","Shortcut")
  Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut(objShell.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Employee Scan Folder.LNK")
lnk.TargetPath = chr(34) & sInput & chr(34)
  lnk.WorkingDirectory = chr(34) & sInput & chr(34)
  lnk.Save
  'Clean up 
  Set lnk = Nothing

Comment: You don't have to change anything. Just run the code as is. It will prompt you to enter the path which you enter like you stated.

Comment: Ah Ok!  I ran the script, and it create the folder, but when I try to double click on it, it's asking me to select which program to use.  Looks like it's not set to use explorer.exe.  Also the icon shows a white page with the shortcut.  Is there a way to have to script force using explorer to open the directory and to have the standard icon for folder shortcuts?

Comment: That's odd. What OS are you using? It works fine for me on win7 32bit. It creates the shortcut with the network folder icon as default. You can specify a custom icon by using lnk.IconLocation "Path to Icon file", index"

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the Icon business, but now it won't open up in explorer.  It keeps prompting me to choose which program to open with.  I do appreciate all your help with this.  I'm slowly learning how to use VBS.

Comment: What happens if you manually create an icon to that folder? It sounds to me like more of a windows issue at this point. Compare the manually created one with the one created from code.

Comment: I can get the icon to work fine. When I try to open the shortcut, it prompts me to use a certain program to use.  It needs to be explorer.exe.  When I choose explorer.exe manually it works, but I need it to stick.  I don't know the VBS code to initiate a program with a file.